# HA OpenVPN with only one IP for the VPN client

Tags: networking, vpn

Goal: allow VPN clients to communicate (udp) with a server.
Setup:

- client must be renseigned only **one public IP**, because we are going through firewall which will not open more than one destination `ip:port`
- server-side must be highly available, so we will have at least 2 VPN servers
- servers-side must be load balanced
- we will have a firewall as internet to LAN gateway

Here is a schema:
[image]

We are currently interested in [pritunl](https://pritunl.com/) but for now we have not succeeded to have only one remote IP.

With OpenVPN (used by pritunl btw) it seems that adding several remote ip and using `remote-random` is the closest solution. 
Any more idea?